# Apex Test Class - After Update Trigger

Tags: trigger, unit-test

I have a test class that is only covering my trigger 48% and I want to get it as close to 100% as possible. It appears there is one section that I am not covering when using the Developer Console but I am not sure how to modify the class to include these rows. The rows where there is no coverage are the rows between:

for(Opportunitylineitem Opplist :opplinitemlist ){
and
RecipeList.add(rec);

Trigger:

```
trigger InsertRecipeSheets on Opportunity (after update){

    List<Recipe_Sheet__c> RecipeList =new List<Recipe_Sheet__c>();
    List<Opportunitylineitem> opplinitemlist =new List<Opportunitylineitem>();
    List<Opportunity> Opportunitylist =new List<Opportunity>();

    for(Opportunity opp :trigger.new){
        if(opp.Create_Recipe_Sheet_s__c==True){       
        Opplinitemlist =[select Id,PricebookEntry.Product2.Name,PricebookEntry.Product2.Do_Not_Discount__c,Wall_Mount_Stem__c,Quantity,PricebookEntry.Product2.Record_Type_ID__c,Total_Drop__c,Finish_s__c,Notes__c, For_Vaulted_Ceiling__c,PricebookEntry.Product2.id from Opportunitylineitem where Opportunityid =: opp.id AND Product2.Do_Not_Discount__c=False AND Product2.Record_Type_ID__c<>''];
        Opportunitylist  =[Select Accountid from Opportunity where Id =: opp.id];

        for(Opportunitylineitem Opplist :opplinitemlist ){
        Recipe_Sheet__c rec =new Recipe_Sheet__c();
        rec.Opportunity__c =Opportunitylist[0].Id;
        rec.product__c=opplist.PricebookEntry.Product2.Id;
        rec.Name=opplist.PricebookEntry.Product2.Name;
        rec.For_Vaulted_Ceiling__c=opplist.For_Vaulted_Ceiling__c;
        rec.Wall_Mount_Stem__c=opplist.Wall_Mount_Stem__c;
        rec.Finish_s__c=opplist.Finish_s__c;
        rec.Notes__c=opplist.Notes__c;
        rec.Total_Drop__c=opplist.Total_Drop__c;
        rec.Quantity__c=opplist.Quantity;
        rec.Status__c='Received by Production';
        rec.RecordTypeID=opplist.PricebookEntry.Product2.Record_Type_ID__c;
        RecipeList.add(rec);
        }
        insert RecipeList;
        } 
        }  
    for(Opportunity Opps :Opportunitylist ){
    Opps.Create_Recipe_Sheet_s__c=False;
    }
    update Opportunitylist;


}
```

Test Class:

```
    @IsTest (OnInstall=true SeeAllData=true) private class TEST_InsertRecipeSheets{


private static testMethod void myUnitTest() {

Account acc=new Account(
    Name='test',
    Resale_Certificate_Number_Tax_ID__c='NA',
    BillingStreet='123',
    BillingCity='portsmouth',
    BillingState='NH',
    BillingpostalCode='03801',
    BillingCountry='US'
);
insert acc;   


Pricebook2 pb = [select id from Pricebook2 where IsStandard = true limit 1];   

//Product2 prods=[select id,name,Do_Not_Discount__c,Record_Type_ID__c  from Product2 where IsActive = true AND Record_Type_ID__c<>'' AND Do_Not_Discount__c= FALSE];   

    // create the product
    Product2 p1= new Product2(
        name='CLOUD 19',
        IsActive=true,
        Description='My Product',
        ProductCode='12345',
        Do_Not_Discount__c=False
        );
    insert p1;

    // create 2nd product
    Product2 p2= new Product2(
        name='TWIG 5',
        IsActive=true,
        Description='My Base Product',
        ProductCode='11111',
        Do_Not_Discount__c=False
        );
    insert p2;


    // create the pricebookentry
        PricebookEntry pbe1 = new PricebookEntry(
        Pricebook2Id=pb.id,
        Product2Id=p1.id,
        UnitPrice=1.00,
        IsActive=true,
        UseStandardPrice=false
    );
    insert pbe1; 

     // create 2nd pricebookentry
        PricebookEntry pbe2 = new PricebookEntry(
        Pricebook2Id=pb.id,
        Product2Id=p2.id,
        UnitPrice=1.00,
        IsActive=true,
        UseStandardPrice=false
    );
    insert pbe2; 


    Item__c i1 =new Item__c(
    Name='Test'
    );
    insert i1;  

    Item__c i2 =new Item__c(
    Name='Test'
    );
    insert i2; 

    Product_Item__c pi1=new Product_Item__c(
    Product__c=p1.id,
    Item__c=i1.id,
    Quantity__c=1,
    External_Wall_Mount_Vaulted_Ceiling__c=2,
    Standard_Item__c=True
    );
    insert pi1;

    Product_Item__c pi2=new Product_Item__c(
    Product__c=p2.id,
    Item__c=i2.id,
    Quantity__c=2,
    External_Wall_Mount_Vaulted_Ceiling__c=3,
    Standard_Item__c=True
    );
    insert pi2;

    Product_Item__c pi3=new Product_Item__c(
    Product__c=p2.id,
    Item__c=i2.id,
    Quantity__c=null,
    External_Wall_Mount_Vaulted_Ceiling__c=null,
    Standard_Item__c=False
    );
    insert pi3;


    // create the opportunity
        Opportunity opp1 = new Opportunity(
        name='Test Opp 1',
        StageName = 'Balance Received',
        CloseDate = Date.newInstance(2009,01,01), 
        Production_Date__c=Date.newInstance(2009,01,01),
        Production_Status__c='Received By Production',
        Create_Recipe_Sheet_s__c=True,
        Pricebook2Id=pb.id         
    );
    insert opp1;


    // add the line item
    OpportunityLineItem oli1 = new OpportunityLineItem(
    Quantity = 1,
    PricebookEntryId = pbe1.id,
    OpportunityId = opp1.id,
    For_Vaulted_Ceiling__c='No',
    Wall_Mount_Stem__c='No',
    UnitPrice=1
    );
    insert oli1;

    OpportunityLineItem oli2 = new OpportunityLineItem(
    Quantity = 2,
    PricebookEntryId = pbe2.id,
    OpportunityId = opp1.id,
    For_Vaulted_Ceiling__c='No',
    Wall_Mount_Stem__c='No',
    UnitPrice = 2
    );  
    insert oli2; 

    update opp1;

    Recipe_Sheet__c RS1 =new Recipe_Sheet__c(
    Opportunity__c=opp1.id,
    Product__c=oli1.PricebookEntry.Product2.Id,
    Status__c='Inventory Committed',
    For_Vaulted_Ceiling__c=oli1.For_Vaulted_Ceiling__c,
    Wall_Mount_Stem__c=oli1.Wall_Mount_Stem__c,
    Name='Test'
    );
    insert RS1; 


    RS1 =  [SELECT Id,Product__c,Status__c FROM Recipe_Sheet__c 
             WHERE Id = :RS1.Id];

    System.assertEquals('Inventory Committed', RS1.Status__c);

    Recipe_Sheet__c RS2 =new Recipe_Sheet__c(
    Opportunity__c=opp1.id,
    Product__c=oli2.PricebookEntry.Product2.Id,
    Status__c='Inventory Committed',
    For_Vaulted_Ceiling__c=oli2.For_Vaulted_Ceiling__c,
    Wall_Mount_Stem__c=oli2.Wall_Mount_Stem__c,
    Recalculate_Recipe_Sheet_Items__c = True,
    Name='Test'
    );
    insert RS2; 


    RS2 =  [SELECT Id,Product__c,Status__c FROM Recipe_Sheet__c 
             WHERE Id = :RS2.Id];

    System.assertEquals('Inventory Committed', RS2.Status__c);

    Recipe_Sheet_Item__c ri1=new Recipe_Sheet_Item__c(
    Recipe_Sheet__c=RS1.id,
    Item__c=i1.id,
    Quantity__c=1
    );
    insert ri1;

    ri1 =  [SELECT Id,Recipe_Sheet__c,Item__c, Quantity__c FROM Recipe_Sheet_Item__c 
             WHERE Id = :ri1.Id];

    System.assertEquals(1, ri1.Quantity__c);


    Recipe_Sheet_Item__c ri2=new Recipe_Sheet_Item__c(
    Recipe_Sheet__c=RS1.id,
    Item__c=i2.id,
    Quantity__c=3
    );
    insert ri2;




          }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never update your Opportunity after you create line items for it.  Try putting:

```
update opp1;
```

at the end.

EDIT:

Also try removing AND `Product2.Do_Not_Discount__c=False AND Product2.Record_Type_ID__c<>''` one at a time and see if that makes a difference.  You might need to add an additional filter to the product you return in your test class.

Comment: I added the "update opp1;" after "insert oli2;" and there was no change in coverage.

Comment: Added an edit to my answer for you to try out.

Comment: Just tried that. No change unfortunately.

Comment: I edited the Test Class above to the most recent version I have.

Answer (score 0):

In your test class, you missed to set the field `Product2.Do_Not_Discount__c=False' and adding a recordtype to it, which fires your trigger.

Also like dphil said, update your opportunity after inserting it.